# Neovim's spell checking doesn't recognize the main word list if using spell file

Tags: neovim

Spell checking in Neovim has a strange behaviour when using multiple languages. When I add a word to my own word list (`de.utf-8.add`, note I'm a German), Neovim generates the `de.utf-8.add.spl` file. That's very nice and convenient. But after restarting Neovim, all words except the ones in my `*.add` file are marked as misspelled. It seems that Neovim recognizes the `de.utf-8.add.spl` only. I use spell checking in the usual way:

```
:set spell spelllang=de_de
```

I put all my spell related file in `~/.local/share/nvim/site/spell/` and my `init.vim` is nothing special:

```
set encoding=utf-8
set spellfile=~/.local/share/nvim/site/spell/de.utf-8.add
```

As few people have this problem, I think must have made a mistake. Could someone help me out?

Answer (score 1):

I am using English and Japanese text.
In my environment, same bug was fixed with using

> :set spell spelllang=en,cjk

Instead of

> :set spell spelllang=cjk